# Regex to delete specific spaces with sed

Tags: linux, bash, sed

I have a text file that looks like this:

```
HETATM11584
HETATM 2514
HETATM22222
HETATM 8585
HETATM 1213
HETATM62626
HETATM 6754
```

There are white spaces separating HETATM from a string of numbers. I want to delete theses white spaces and output a new file that looks like this:

```
HETATM11584
HETATM2514
HETATM22222
HETATM8585
HETATM1213
HETATM62626
HETATM6754
```

I tried to use sed

```
sed 's/.*HETATM [1-9]*.*/.*HETATM[1-9]*.*/' HETATM.txt > teste.txt
```

But the output looks like this:

```
HETATM11584
.*HETATM[1-9]*.*
HETATM22222
.*HETATM[1-9]*.*
.*HETATM[1-9]*.*
HETATM62626
.*HETATM[1-9]*.*
```

What is the proper sed synthax for this operation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use a pattern as the substitution string. You can remove the space from your string using [backreference](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Back_002dreferences-and-Subexpressions.html):

```
sed 's/\(HETATM\) \([0-9]\)/\1\2/'  HETATM.txt > teste.txt
```

`HETATM` and digits are captured with parenthesis. Captured strings are output(without space) with `\1` and `\2`.

Answer (score 2):

If the whole file is like your example, the easiest way would be removing all the spaces:

```
$ sed -r 's/ //g' file.txt
HETATM11584
HETATM2514
HETATM22222
HETATM8585
HETATM1213
HETATM62626
HETATM6754
```

If the file is composed by whatever followed by space(s) and a ending with a number, then this will do it:

```
$ sed -r 's/ +([0-9]+)$/\1/g' file.txt
HETATM11584
HETATM2514
HETATM22222
HETATM8585
HETATM1213
HETATM62626
HETATM6754
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have to use `sed`?

```
$ tr -d ' ' < HETATM.txt > teste.txt
```

might serve your purpose as well.